# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, promise which was not handled with .catch()

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I hope you can help me, I have been using node.js for a short time and only a week with puppeteer and I have made a small excrip to automate a task, when running the script it performs the process correctly at a glance.

---

However, the console throws me two types of errors:

1st - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: waiting for selector `.flexMain> div> div> #PageContent_AuthorisedButtons> .btn` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
at new WaitTask

2nd - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch ().

---

I would appreciate help to solve the problem since I have been stuck and do not see the solution.

---

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    try {

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            userDataDir: "./cache",
            ignoreDefaultArgs: [
                "--disable-extensions",
                "--enable-automation"
            ],
            args: [
                "--no-sanbox",
                "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
                "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
                "--disable-gpu"
            ]
        })

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        page.setRequestInterception(true);
        page.on("request", async req => {
            if (req.url().endsWith(".png")) {
                req.abort();
            } else {
                req.continue();
                
                await page.waitForSelector('.flexMain > div > div > #PageContent_AuthorisedButtons > .btn');
                await page.click('.flexMain > div > div > #PageContent_AuthorisedButtons > .btn');
            }


        });



        page.on('error', e => console.log(e));

        await page.goto('http://example.com');

        await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 926 });

        await page.waitForSelector('.flexMain > div > div > #PageContent_UnauthorisedButtons > .btn');
        await page.click('.flexMain > div > div > #PageContent_UnauthorisedButtons > .btn');

        await page.type('.row #SignInEmailInput', 'example@gmail.com');

        await page.waitForSelector('.col-md-7 > #SignInForm > .form-group > div:nth-child(2) > a');
        await page.click('.col-md-7 > #SignInForm > .form-group > div:nth-child(2) > a');

        const collectCaptcha = await page.$('#adcopy-puzzle-image-image');
        collectCaptcha.screenshot({ path: 'src/img/capture-captcha.png' });

        const urlImageCaptcha = path.join(__dirname, 'img/capture-captcha1.png');

        // page.waitForTimeout(10000)


        // await browser.close()

    }
    catch (e) {

    }

})()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `page.on("request", ...)` handler, you declare it as an `async` callback and you use `await`, yet you don't catch any exceptions from the await.  Put a `try/catch` are the code in that callback.

```
   page.on("request", async req => {
        if (req.url().endsWith(".png")) {
            req.abort();
        } else {
            req.continue();

            // ==> you don't catch rejections from either of these await statments  <==
            await page.waitForSelector('.flexMain > div > div > #PageContent_AuthorisedButtons > .btn');
            await page.click('.flexMain > div > div > #PageContent_AuthorisedButtons > .btn');
        }
    });
```

You can catch these possible rejections with this:

```
   page.on("request", async req => {
      try {
        if (req.url().endsWith(".png")) {
            req.abort();
        } else {
            req.continue();

            await page.waitForSelector('.flexMain > div > div > #PageContent_AuthorisedButtons > .btn');
            await page.click('.flexMain > div > div > #PageContent_AuthorisedButtons > .btn');
        }
      } catch(e) {
           console.log(e);
           // do something here with the error
      }
    });
```

FYI, this code doesn't appear to actually do anything.  you await a select and then a click, but then don't do anything after those occur.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have been hours trying to solve it and I am not able to do it, I always get the same error, you would be so kind to write the correct code.

Comment: @RobertArmand - There's code in my answer.  Please check again.

Comment: thanks the previous error has been solved, but now these two new ones appear, the script works fine but it is driving me crazy ..

- Error: Protocol error (DOM.resolveNode): Node with given id does not belong to the document at Promise.

- message:
    'Protocol error (DOM.resolveNode): Node with given id does not belong to the document'}
{Error: Protocol error (DOM.resolveNode): Node with given id does not belong to the document at Promise

Comment: jfriend00 I have managed to solve the problem, thanks to your explanation.